# What is the discrete equivalent of the powerlaw distribution?

Tags: modeling, power-law

The question is all in the title. The only background I can add, is that I am finding a powerlaw to interpolate beautifully between my data points. Only that my data appears in integers only, so I would better use the discrete equivalent of the powerlaw distribution - that is to say, a probability density function equal to $ax^{-b}$ with $a$ and $b$ positive, and $x > 1$ - to use it for a Monte Carlo simulation. From a quick googling it seems like a Zeta distribution might be what I need, but I am unsure.

Comment: Can you make it more precise what do you mean by powerlaw distribution?

Comment: Thanks Tim - just edited the question. Do not know yet how to use Latex in CrossValidated though

Comment: You haven't defined the domain of $x$ though, nor what $ax^{-b}$ represents (the pmf? the survivor function? something else?) so your definition is incomplete (and different authors use different definitions!). On using the subset of LaTeX implemented in MathJax, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks Glen, hope my last edit contains all relevant infos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a discrete distribution where $P(X=x)\propto x^{-\alpha}$ for $x=1,2,3,...$ then you would have a [zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution).

If you want a discrete distribution where $P(X=x)\propto x^{-\alpha}$ for $x=1,2,3,...,N$ then you would have a truncated zeta distribution, also known as [Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf's_law).

On the other hand, if (as at least some authors do) you define a power law up to a [slowly varying function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function#Basic_definitions), $L(x)$ -- i.e. where say

$P(X=x) = L(x)\cdot x^{-\alpha}\,,\quad  x=1,2,3,...$

or

$P(X\gt x) = L(x)\cdot x^{-\alpha}\,,\quad x=1,2,3,...$

then neither of these is a zeta unless $L$ is the identity. Indeed, this definition encompasses an infinity of distributions

Comment: Is there a typo here? The two scalings you put forth are the same.

Comment: That's not a scaling (well, it will implictly include a scaling constant - different in both cases - but it's some "slowly varying function" as specified immediately above those two lines). I've made a small edit.

Comment: [`scipy.stats.zipf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zipf.html) appears to implement the [zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) while [`scipy.stats.zipfian`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zipfian.html) implements the [Zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf's_law). Confusing terminology, to say the least.